# How to bring mysql database values in java servlets using href

Tags: java, servlets

I am trying to fetch data from my database using href and I am unable to do that any help will be appreciatable my code is

```
<a style="color:black"  href='Blog_Servlet.java?blog_id=1' >continue reading</a></p><br>
```

Comment: <a style="color:black"  href='Blog_Servlet.java?blog_id=1' >continue reading this is my code through which I am tryng to bring data

Comment: This is a servlet .. either you map this servlet using web.xml or using java annotations..

Comment: This will not work. Your HREF is point to a java file. while it should point to a Servlet. Another this Are you exceptiong the value to be replace at href="Value" or you want you page to get redireced on click.

Comment: Please also mention what you really want to achieve so we may help you.

Comment: i actually want the data to be retrieved from database when clicking on href this is the code (<a href='blog_servlet?blog_id'>) but its not fetchng the data only displayng the blank page